# Hue 3.10.0 not connecting to custom JDBC server (An error occurred while calling z:java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection)

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hiveql, hue, jdbc-odbc

I am able to connect to my custom JDBC server able to handle SQL queries via source code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class HiveConnector {
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        //replace "hive" here with the name of the user the queries should run as
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000", "{username}", "{password}");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String tableName = "`tableName`";
        String sql = "select * from " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

I followed the instruction at http://gethue.com/custom-sql-query-editors/ and have downloaded hue 3.10.0 binary and did "make install". I changed my hue.ini file for notebook hive to

`[[[hive]]]
      name=My Hive
      interface=jdbc
      options='{"url": "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000", "driver": "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "user": "{username}", "password": "{password}"}'`

I logged into my hue UI and navigated to notebook "My Hive" and noticed following error. [0]
**I am just wondering what I am doing wrong? Here is my CLASSPATH for Java [1] which have few extra jars.**

[1]: export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/lib/myCustom/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/lib/myCustom/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar:/usr/local/lib/myCustom/hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar:$CLASSPATH

[0]: An error occurred while calling z:java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection. : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)